# Where can the Eclipse compiler be found?

Tags: java, eclipse

usually, the compiler is in the lower right corner and pops up when you click on it
or when you have made an error. now i cant even find it. how do you call it up again?

Comment: Hmmm. Were you using ant to build your projects?  It's usually simpler just to turn on Build Automatically from the project menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your description it looks like you're looking for the **console** not the **compiler**

If so, look in:

Window --> Show View --> Console

Comment: thanks...i dont have enough to vote this up but i take ur answer! ^.^

Comment: No problem, there goes +1 to your question so you can start voting soon :) Cheers

PS: Can't you still pick an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this by clicking
"Window" -> Show View -> Problems

Answer (score 0):

You probably switched perspectives.  Find the Java perspective in the menu or upper right corner, and switch to it.

If you accidentally closed the Problems or Markers view, you can re-open them through the menu.

Comment: @thynoob, on stackoverflow you express thanks by upvoting answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also click  **Window > Reset Perspective**. This is helpful when views get closed or lost in workspace.